# Que veut dire le mot « arrière-propos » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Que veut dire le mot arrière-propos ? Je l’ai rencontré par hasard en introduisant quelque chose dans la boite de recherche du Wiktionnaire. Je ne sais donc pas encore si c’est utile d’apprendre ce mot. Wiktionnaire me disait seulement ceci quant à son sens, sans donner d'exemples de son emploi :

> Propos désobligeants qu'on tient sur le compte d'une personne après qu'elle est partie.

J’avais du mal à comprendre cette explication, j’ai donc cherché une traduction dans un dictionnaire français-néerlandais disponible sur la toile, mais celui-ci ne me donne que des traductions des composants « arrière » et « propos » séparément. J’ai aussi utilisé Google pour chercher quelques emplois mais sans succès. Ceci me fait douter du fait que ce mot ait encore cours.

Ici, je donne une esquisse de ce que je pensais du mot moi-même. Tout d’abord, c’est quelque chose que quelqu’un dit. Il me semble qu’on tient un arrière-propos lorsqu’on dit ne pas devoir faire quelque chose. Par exemple, si mon père me dit que je dois nettoyer le sol du rez-de-chaussée, et qu'après il sort la maison, lorsque je dis à ma mère « je ne vais rien nettoyer, je n’en ai pas envie », est-ce que je tiens un arrière-propos ?

Quel composants requiert ce mot ? Faut-il un interlocuteur pour faire un arrière-propos ? Et à l’égard de la « personne qui est partie », doit-elle être une personne puissante qui exige qu’un boulot soit rempli ? Finalement, est-ce qu’un « arrière-propos » exprime du mécontentement, ou est-ce plutôt un faire-part pour les gens qui sont encore là ?

**Ma question** : Bref, je veux savoir si connaître ce mot en vaut la peine. Si oui, voulez-vous m’en expliquer le sens ?

Comment: *Je veux savoir si connaître ce mot en vaut la peine?* De fait, c'est la première fois que j'entend cette expression. Dans ce sens, il n'est pas nécessaire de l'apprendre. D'un autre coté, il est trop tard pour l'oublier....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je pense, au vu de votre définition, que l'expression recherchée est *Casser du sucre sur le dos de quelqu'un*. Pour reprendre une description trouvée [sur *l'Internaute*](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/4522/casser-du-sucre-sur-le-dos-de-quelqu-un/) :

> Dire du mal d'une personne lorsqu'elle est absente.
>
> L'expression date de la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Ici le dos fait allusion à l'absence de l'individu sur qui on dit du mal. En effet, il est toujours plus facile de dire les critiques lorsqu'on est pas en face de la personne concernée. De plus, le dos permet de porter de lourds fardeaux, ce qui image le fait de remettre la faute sur quelqu'un qui est absent. Le sens de "casser du sucre" signifie "dire du mal de quelqu'un". Ainsi en combinant les deux extraits de l'expression, on obtient son sens complet : action de dire du mal d'un individu en son absence.

Ou encore une *arrière-pensée* (source : [*l'Internaute*](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/arriere-pensee/)) :

> Pensée ou intention que l'on dissimule tandis qu'on en exprime une autre.

Pour moi un arrière-propos est une partie d'un livre qui permet d'ajouter des informations complémentaires relatives au contenu du livre (épilogue). Au même titre que l'avant propos qui permet lui, de créer un contexte de départ pour le livre (prologue).

Comment: Moi aussi j'ai pensé au contraire d'*avant-propos* (je n'emploierais pas *épilogue* comme synonyme, car ce mot est trop associé à la fiction pour moi).

Comment: [Le plagiat, c'est pas cool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Answer (score 0):

Je n'ai jamais lu "arrière-propos".
À la rigueur, on pourrait en faire un antonyme de l'ancien sens d'avant-propos :

> Ce qu'on dit avant de venir au fait, quand on entreprend de raconter
> quelque chose. Il a fait un avant-propos bien inutile`` (Dictionnaire de l'Académie française de 1798 à 1932).

Mais ce serait plus simplement une conclusion.

Un auteur aurait-il utilisé ce mot pour une postface ? J'en doute.

Je n'intègrerai pas ce mot dans le mégadictionnaire.